# Python ```and``` two bool list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
[True,False,True,False] and [True,True,False,False]
```

it returns :

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

Why is the second element is `True` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Python doesn't do element-wise vector operations like that.  The way the normal `and` operator works is, if the first operand has a "true" value, then the result is the second value.  Your first list is not empty, so it's true, so it returned the entire second list.

The `numpy` module does element-wise operations like that, but not straight Python.